# How to add a List of Parent objects to a List of Child Objects

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Consider a parent class named `PowerHost`. Consider a child class named `PowerHostHistory` which is like this:

```
PowerHostHistory extends PowerHost
```

I have a list of child class defined like this which is constantly filled with `PowerHostHistory` objects.

```
List<PowerHostHistory> excludedHosts = new LinkedList<PowerHostHistory>();
```

Now, in a bit different way, I am going to add a list of `PowerHost` objects to my `excludedHosts`.

I want to add a list of parent objects to a list of child objects. Is that possible, and how?

Comment: There will be `ClassCastException` at runtime.

Comment: You mean it is not possible!

Comment: if you want to add parent to a list of children,then there will be classCastException,but the vice versa will work

Comment: It will be better if you create a List of Parents and then you can add both child and parent in that List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by simply casting away the generic type:

```
PowerHost powerHost = ...
((List)excludedHosts).add(powerHost);
```

but it does not make sense: You declared `excludedHosts` to be of type `List<PowerHostHistory>` and then you add some non `PowerHostHistory` objects.
Everyone who is using the list elements will be surprised.

You should decide if you want a list of `PowerHostHistory`: then don't add `PowerHost` objects to it. Or you want a list of `PowerHost` and then of course you can add the `PowerHost` objects.

Comment: I defined excludedHost a list of PowerHostHistory, and I can add this type of objects easily, but for some reason i have to add a list of PowerHost objects which is parent object to this list too. your definition of excludedHost is wrong because I want excludedHost to be  PowerHostHistory not PowerHost.

Comment: Casting away the generic as suggested by @wero will let you add the parent in a List of Child

Comment: But I think @wero change my reference type to  powerHost. i don't want that. I want my excludedHosts to be in PowerHostHistory type as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @vahidkhoshdel can you add a code snippet what you are actually trying to do when you talk about adding a PowerHost to the excludedHosts list.

Comment: excludedHosts.addAll(getSwitchedOffHosts()); where getSwitchedOffHosts() is a method that return a list of PowerHost objects and defined like this protected List<PowerHost> getSwitchedOffHosts();

Comment: @vahidkhoshdel: no this is not possible, the compiler does not allow it. And as I wrote in my answer, this does not make sense, since a `PowerHost` in general **is not** a `PowerHostHistory`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add parent object by downCasting. You can do like :

```
excludedHosts.add((PowerHostHistory)new PowerHost());
```

But it will give RunTime exception

Instead why don`t you do like this :

```
List<PowerHost> excludedHosts = new LinkedList<PowerHost>();

        excludedHosts.add(new PowerHost());
        excludedHosts.add(new PowerHostHistory());
```

Then you can add both.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: You are changing my excludedHosts definition too. Why changing it. There is no other way?

Comment: @vahid..you are not getting the parent and child relation, if you want a list of child ,then you can`t add parent object. If you want to add both then you have take list as parent. When you want to iterate the list, then you can easily check that added object is of type parent or child.

Comment: So, I have to change excludedHosts to PowerHost which is parent class right?

Comment: Nops, you should have your list of type PowerHost if you want to add both the objects.

Comment: Please hit +1 if you like answer. Thanks !!